# Select visible elements in css selectors (querySelector)

Tags: css, css-selectors, queryselector

Eg.

```
<div style="display:none">
    <span id=test style="display:none"></span>
</div>
```

I know in jquery you can do `:visible`

I tried something like `:not([display=none]) > span` but this will also select nested invisible elements. Eg:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(':not([display=none]) > span').forEach(elem =>
    console.log(elem.id)
);
```

```html
<div id=d style="display:none">
    <div id=dd>
      <span id=dds></span>
    </div>
    <span id=ds></span>
</div>
```

Is there anyone to make a selector that would only accept visible elements?

If there were an AND selector I could do something like the following:

```
:and(
    :not([display=none]) > span,
    :not([display=none]) > * > span,
    :not([display=none]) > * > * > span,

    etc.
)
```

These are my best workarounds:

---

```
function* allVisibleElems(parent = document)
{
    for (let elem of parent.children)
    {
        if (elem.style.display === 'none') continue;
        yield elem;
        yield* allVisibleElems(elem);
    }
}
```

This function would have equivalent functionality to `document.querySelectorAll(':visible')`.

---

```
function isVisible (elem)
{
    while (elem !== document)
    {
        if (elem.style.display === 'none') return false;
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This function would have equivalent functionality to `elem.matches(':visible')`.

---

**Note:** these solutions only work when setting the `style.display` property to `none` but that is all I need for my application.

Comment: I would be happy to but I don't think that would make the question any easier. `:not(.invisible) span` has the same issue.

Comment: i miss jquery somethimes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach( sp =>
  {
  let
    pDiv = sp.closest('div')
  , pDivOK = true
    ;
  while(pDivOK && pDiv)
    {
    pDivOK &&= (getComputedStyle(pDiv).display != 'none')
    pDiv = pDiv.parentNode.closest('div')
    }
  if ( pDivOK )
    console.log( sp.id, "<-- parents '<div' are all visible")
  });
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="d" style="display:none">
  <div id="dd">
    <span id="dds"></span>
  </div>
  <span id="ds"></span>
</div>


<div id="1d" class="noDisplay">
  <div id="1dd">
    <span id="1dds"></span>
  </div>
  <span id="1ds"></span>
</div>
  
    
<div id="2d">
  <span id="2ds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not wrong but I was looking for a css selector. I already provided a workaround.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 No, I think you are looking for the impossible, this kind of selector does not exist in CSS

Comment: @trinalbadger587 The issue is that CSS, including its selectors, is "dead", static, meaning it works with declarations, not with computed values which are only available for the browser's engine, hence only accessible via Javascript.